# Changing output directories/files to lowercase in Gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-less, asp.net-core-1.0, gulp-rename, task-runner-explorer

I'm using Gulp to automatically copy/bundle/compile my files, I basically copy the entire folder structure from the base folder (MyProject/Scripts) to wwwroot/js.

In the process of copying/processing I want to rename the output path/filenames to lowercase. I found the ChangeCase-module and the Rename-module but I can't get it to work in my setup below.

```
gulp.task("compile:less", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.lessSrc)
        .pipe(less())
        //how can I get to currentdirectory so I can use it for the rename? maybe there is another way
        //.pipe(rename({ dirname: changeCase.lowerCase(??currentdir??) }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssTarget));
});
```

and

```
gulp.task("compile:js", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.jsOrigin)
        //simple copy of folders and files but how to rename all to lowercase?
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsTarget));
});
```

Comment: Did you try just putting that kind of syntax: dirname: changeCase.lowerCase()? So you just use function for dirname renaming.

Comment: Haven't tried but answer below worked :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback function to `gulp-rename`:

```
gulp.task("compile:js", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.jsOrigin)
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
       path.dirname = changeCase.lowerCase(path.dirname);
       path.basename = changeCase.lowerCase(path.basename);
       path.extname = changeCase.lowerCase(path.extname);
     })) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsTarget));
});
```

Comment: Instead of

`path.dirname = changeCase.lowerCase(path.dirname);
 path.basename = changeCase.lowerCase(path.basename);
 path.extname = changeCase.lowerCase(path.extname);`

I think it should be:

`path.dirname = path.dirname.toLowerCase();
 path.basename = path.basename.toLowerCase();
 path.extname = path.extname.toLowerCase();`